# Symfony: Convert two entities that extend the same class

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

Maybe there are already answers regarding this topic but I cannot find any information. If there are answers already, just post any links.

My question is:

I work with Symfony 2.5 and doctrine 2

A common problem I have is that I have an entity that I want to persist to different tables in the database. For this I usually create a superclass and extend it in two concrete entities that I persist to the database.

Now I have two entities deriving from the same base class. Is it possible to convert from one to another. Of course I have to persist them to the database separately.

One example. I have two classes: "quote" and "order" which are basically the same and extend the superclass "project"

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class project {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description; 

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\Customer")
     */
    private $customer;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\CustomerContact")
     */
    private $customercontact;

    ... (getters/setters etc.)
}

class quote extends project { ... }
class order extends project { ... }
```

Now once a quote is confirmed I want to "convert" it to an order and keep all the base data (stored in the "project" part). Also I want to keep the quote itself so I kind of want to create a new order from the quote instead of using the "project" directly and just set a status there.

Of course I could write a constructor or something but I am searching for a way to clone that part of an object.

Maybe there is an alternative way where the class is not extended but the "project"-part is used within the class itself. Not sure but it seems to me like a lot of people could have run into such a problem already and there might be a smart solution for this kind of situation.

I'm happy with any links to docs too if applicable.

Comment: Why don't you use N-to-N mapping instead of Superclasses? Then you can do a `$order = new Order();` and then `$order->setProject($quote->getProject());`... much simpler and now you're not muddying up your data.

Comment: Thought about that. Though this means that all "projects" are stored in the same table which I try to avoid. In case I need to modify something later, this will become complicated. Also I think it is easier to query the database directly if they are separated. Maybe I have to overthink this ...

Comment: use class table inheritance instead of MappedSuperClass, then you can convert by simply change the discriminator value http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance

Comment: Thanks for that tip but I think this comes pretty much down to the same result only that now there's no extra table for the relation between the superclass project and the subclasses quote/order since it is stored within the project-table itself. What I am looking for is something where I can store the same object/entity in two different tables and in the other direction create an object that could serve as (part of) either one or the other.

Comment: It's more of an idea than a solution. Maybe I can put the copy-part within the constructor of the superclass. The constructor takes any object and checks if it "is_subclass_of". If so, all values can be taken and prepopulated. This is probably what I'm gonna do.